# I get a parser error: expected identifier got lparen constructor in remix.

Tags: solidity

I get a parser error: expected identifier got lparen constructor in remix. Following is the full code. Appreciate some advise to solve this.

pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Escrow {

```
enum State {AWAITING_PAYMENT, AWAITING_DELIVERY, COMPLETE, REFUNDED}
State public currentState;

modifier buyerOnly() { require (msg.sender == buyer || msg.sender == arbiter); _;}

modifier sellerOnly() { require (msg.sender == seller || msg.sender == arbiter); _;}

modifier inState (State expectedState) { require (currentState == expectedState); _;}

address public buyer;
address public seller;
address public arbiter;

constructor(address _buyer, address _seller, address _arbiter) public {
    buyer = _buyer;
    seller = _seller;
    arbiter = _arbiter;
}


function sendPayment()buyerOnly inState (State.AWAITING_PAYMENT)public payable {
    currentState == State.AWAITING_DELIVERY;
}

function confirmDelivery()buyerOnly inState (State.AWAITING_DELIVERY)public payable {
    seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
    currentState == State.COMPLETE;
}

function refundBuyer() sellerOnly inState (State.AWAITING_DELIVERY)public payable {
    seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
    currentState == State.REFUNDED;
}

}
```

Comment: Pasted your code in remix and its fine, maybe you forgot change compiler version in remix (Compile tab -> select new compiler version -> 0.4.25)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve this by using a compiler comaptable with 0.4.25 and it worked. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @BadriNarrayen Hi, Please write an answer and make it accepted. This way anyone easily can find the issue resolution here.